# Why are my firebase callbacks being triggered multiple times?

Tags: node.js, email, firebase

I've got a small node server listening for changes in firebase and sending emails on certain conditions. Here's the code:

```
var Firebase = require('firebase'); 
var ref = new Firebase(process.env.FIREBASE_URL);
ref.authWithCustomToken(process.env.FIREBASE_SECRET, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(new Date().toString(), 'Firebase Authentication Failed!', err);
        EmailService.send('Firebase authentication failed', 'errors@domain.com', err);
    } else {
        ref.child('applicants').on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
            var applicant = snapshot.val();
            if (!(applicant.alerts && applicant.alerts.apply)) {
                console.log(new Date().toString(), 'New Applicant: ', applicant);
                var body = applicant.firstName + ' ' + applicant.lastName + '\n' + applicant.email + '\n' + applicant.phoneNumber;
                EmailService
                .send('New Applicant', 'applicants@entercastle.com', body)
                .then(function () {                
                    ref.child('applicants').child(snapshot.key()).child('alerts').child('apply').set(true);
                })
               .catch(function (err) { console.log(new Date().toString(), err); });
            }
        });
    }                                                                                                                                                    
});
```

However, I keep getting duplicate emails. The weirdest part is, the logs only show a single "New Applicant : ..." statement for each applicant, despite multiple emails being sent.

Any ideas what's causing this or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child_added events will be triggered each time authWithCustomToken() succeeds. Each time the page is reloaded or reauthenticated, new listeners are attached, and each user will trigger a new child_added event, and the emails will be resent.

> The child_added event is typically used when retrieving a list of
>   items in Firebase. Unlike value which returns the entire contents of
>   the location, child_added **is triggered once for each existing child**
>   and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path.
>   The event callback is passed a snapshot containing the new child's
>   data.

(emphasis mine)

If you only ever want to send the emails once, a better approach would be to use a [queue strategy](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue), where you "queue" an activity (e.g. welcome email) when a user is created.

Then your service can read the queue and delete the task once they successfully complete. In this way, you won't have dups.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the `if (!(applicant.alerts && applicant.alerts.apply))` would account for child_added triggering once for each existing child. It seems like the auth callback is getting called multiple times and causing the listeners to attach multiple times so I added a boolean called firstLoad that I check in the auth callback before registering the listeners, but I'm still getting duplicates. I'll probably end up going the queue route, but I'd still like to know what I'm missing. Any thoughts, @Kato?

Comment: There's not enough code in the question to help you figure out why it's called more than once, other than the fact that the auth method may be getting called more than once, and that it will be called for each record, each time the page loads. I'm sure some variant of this is at play but without an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry @Kato, I cleaned up the code a bit in an attempt to make it more mcv. Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/lowe0292/fa3737fdabdff4059629). Thanks!

Comment: I think you're still just confused on the behavior. As written, the script will only send notifications exactly once. However, each time the script restarts, it's going to trigger all the child_added events again, assuming those records still exist. Thus, the answer is still to use a queue where you delete the entries, if they must be sent exactly once.

Comment: I can't be sure why setting `alerts/apply` to true isn't accomplishing the same effect, but most likely that value is not actually set to true in your database (if it were, this couldn't happen). It may be that you are exiting the script prematurely, causing those writes to fail/never occur. Again, these are blind guesses. The critical details are still missing, and there is a lot of investigating you could do to narrow the problem set.

Comment: I agree there's something I don't understand! You said, "As written, the script will only send notifications exactly once. However, each time the script restarts, it's going to trigger all the child_added events again, assuming those records still exist." However, this is a long-running node process that doesn't restart. Just running it once in node still causes duplicate emails to be sent. Also, `alerts/appy` **is** being set to true in my database, as verified in the dashboard. What do you recommend as next steps for narrowing the problem set? As always, thanks so much for all the help

Comment: For reference, I'm using the *Firebase-powered app with server code* architecture from [this blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-03-25-where-does-firebase-fit.html).

Answer (score 2):

removing existing listener before adding new listener will fix this issue

try this `off()` event, before `on()` event

```
ref.child('applicants').off(); // it will remove existing listener
```

then your code

```
ref.child('applicants').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var applicant = snapshot.val();
    if (!(applicant.alerts && applicant.alerts.apply)) {
        console.log(new Date().toString(), 'New Applicant: ', applicant);
        var body = applicant.firstName + ' ' + applicant.lastName + '\n' + applicant.email + '\n' + applicant.phoneNumber;
        EmailService
            .send('New Applicant', 'applicants@entercastle.com', body)
            .then(function() {
                ref.child('applicants').child(snapshot.key()).child('alerts').child('apply').set(true);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(new Date().toString(), err);
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my issue.

Comment: Can you check this issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74875587/onvalue-triggering-multiple-times

It is similar but I'm confused how and where to use off()