# onValue triggering multiple times

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, discord.js

I'm using Node.js v18.12.1 and Discord.js v14. for developing the Discord bot. I need to read some data from Firebase. I'm confused because I'm used to how Java with Hibernate fetches data differently. Here, I need to use `onValue()` listener.

My `onValue()` acts strange. Instead of just reading the data from Firebase, it skips entirely, then it triggers multiple times, each time skipping the body block of its code, and then it actually does the code after.

I've read somewhere on this forum that this can happen because there are more `onValue()` listeners that are subscribed and they are all fired up. Someone mentioned I need to use the `off()` function somewhere "before" the `onValue()`. This confuses me because I'm using this listener in many locations. I need it in each command file, in `execute(interaction)` functions. You know, when you need to execute slash commands in Discord. I have it something like this:

```
async execute(interaction) {
    const infographicRef = ref(db, '/infographics/arena/' + interaction.options.getString("arena-team"));
    var imageUrl = null;
    var postUrl = null;

    onValue(infographicRef, (snapshot) => {
        imageUrl = snapshot.child("image-url").val();
        
        interaction.reply(imageUrl);
    })
},
```

And I planned for each command, in each command.js file to have `onValue()`. I'm not sure exactly what to do.

Also, I tried to work around this with `once()` method, I see it in Firebase documentation, but I got the error: `ref.once() is not a function`.

It seems that after first triggering of onValue method when the body is not executed, my code in `interactionCreate.js` is triggered as well, it points for a command to be executed again:

```
const { Events } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.InteractionCreate,
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

        const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        if (!command) {
            console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
            return;
        }

        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error executing ${interaction.commandName}`);
            console.error(error);
        }
    },
};
```

my `bot.js` (which is in my case an index file)

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}


client.commands = new Collection();
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));



for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.once(Events.ClientReady, () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});


client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Your question is rather long, but if you want to read a value once in the v9 SDK, have a look at the code sample in the documentaiton here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web-version-9_3 (in the v9 and later SDKs, the function is called `get()` rather than the old `once()` method)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, it seems it works in the debugger. I'm sorry for asking another question, but do I use `await interaction.reply(imageUrl);` in the wrong way? I've got an `Uknown interaction error`, so I can't test it to the end now.
Also, a weird thing, `await get` triggered multiple times as well, although it did provide correct data to interaction.replay

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have used `await interaction.reply({content: imageUrl});` and it works but I've got exception:
`Uncaught DiscordjsError Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.`, then the bot crashes

Comment: Sorry, but just adds more possible topics to an already overloaded question. I recommend posting a more focused question after (re)reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry, I thought the answer would be very short. I'll try to do some research and if I don't find anything I will ask that in a separate question.
Meanwhile, you can post your answer about `get()` (your first comment) so I can vote for you, to earn more points, I wish to give it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onValue` function registers a realtime listener, that continues to monitor the value on the database.

If you want to read a value once, that'd be done with `get()` function in v9 (which is the equivalent of the `once` method in earlier SDK versions). Have a look at the code sample in the documentation on [reading data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web-version-9_3).